# Pass active sheet to a sub routine

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2013, I have a worksheet (named "ChartSheet") which has six charts. I'm trying to automatically set the minimum and maximum values of the Y axis of each chart, upon any change within the worksheet. The values for the minimum and maximum values for each chart are contained within named ranges, specific to the `ChartSheet` worksheet, called `rng_MaxAxis` and `rng_MinAxis`.

In order to accomplish my goal I have the following VBA code in the *ChartSheet* sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    FormatCharts
End Sub
```

This feeds off of a SubRoutine I have in a module called `FormatCharts` and the code in that is:

```
Sub FormatCharts()

Dim objCht As ChartObject
Dim maxAxis As Range
Dim minAxis As Range

Set maxAxis = ActiveSheet.Range("rng_MaxAxis")
Set minAxis = ActiveSheet.Range("rng_MinAxis")

For Each objCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    With objCht.Chart
     ' Value (Y) Axis
        With .Axes(xlValue)
            For Each maxValue In maxAxis
                .MaximumScale = maxValue.Value
            Next maxValue

            For Each minValue In minAxis
                .MinimumScale = minValue.Value
            Next minValue
        End With
    End With
Next objCht

End Sub
```

Upon any change I receive the following error, `Compile Error: Variable not found` and it points to the `maxValue` For Each loop.

I believe this is due to Excel not knowing which worksheet to pass to the `FormartCharts` subroutine. How can I pass the active sheet to the `FormatCharts` subroutine?

Comment: `Sub FormatCharts(ws as worksheet)` then when you call `FormatCharts ActiveSheet`  Then replace all the active sheets in the procedure with ws.

Comment: Call `FormatCharts Target.Parent` after adding a `ws` parameter to `FormatCharts` as Scott describes

Comment: @TimWilliams that was what I couldn't think of right of the top of my head.  It's been one of those days today.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I know those days...

Comment: @TimWilliams and Scott, I think that the problem is elsewhere. I dont see how `ActiveSheet` would be anything else than the sheet where the change actually occured?

Comment: OP, if you are using `Option Explicit`, I dont see where your variable `maxValue` is defined?

Comment: ASH has your actual problem, but still it's best to *never* use `ActiveSheet`/`Selection` etc in your code unless you absolutely need to (and in most cases it can be avoided).  What if (for example) you end up writing code which updates your Chart sheet and that gets run while the sheet isn't active?